# How do i pass a function with props.history(path, state) in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i am facing problem on my react project, what I am doing, I pushing the route through `props.history` which contain two params `(path, State)`, on state passing object which contain some keys and function. when i add a function in state object it's give me error. can somebody help me to get out of this issue.

Here is my code.

```
const { history } = this.props;
        const data= {
           index: this.props.index,
           detail: this.props.object,
           handleSubmit: () => { console.log("i am not passing :(");}
        }
        history.push('/update-task/${index}', data);
```

here is screenshot of error: [image]

**NOTE:** when i just pass simple object and string value then it's working fine and i get the value like `props.location.state.key`

above code was working on react-router v3 but in react-router-dom not working.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @dfsq please check http://prntscr.com/gw03qj

Comment: The error is very clear, you can't pass function into history state.

Comment: @dfsq is there any way to send a function to other component ?

Comment: you can pass a function via prop from parent to child.

Comment: I think you are truing to solve xy-problem. There might be better way.